# Express "BasicAuth" with async checking of credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, basic-authentication

I'm migrating Express from 3.x to 4.x and since Express 4 doesn't have `basicAuth`, I'm trying to replace it with [`basic-auth` module](https://github.com/jshttp/basic-auth).

The problem I'm experiencing is with async checking of credentials (via my `user_tools.checkCredentials()` method).

This is how it **worked** with 3.x:

```
var auth = function(req, res, next) {
  isFromLAN(req.ip, function(fromLAN) {
    if (fromLAN) {
      // console.log('LAN --> no auth needed');
      next();
    } else {
      // console.log(req.ip + ' --> WAN --> auth to pass');
      basicAuth(function(user, pass, callback) {
        user_tools.checkCredentials(user, pass, function(valid) {
         callback(null, valid);
        });
      })(req, res, next);
    }
  });
};
```

Current code, silently failing at checkCredentials:

```
var express = require('express');
var basicAuth = require('basic-auth');
var user_tools = require('./user-tools');

var app = express();

var auth = function(req, res, next) {
  function isFromLAN(ip) {
    console.log('isFromLAN()', ip);
    if (ip === '127.0.0.1') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  if (isFromLAN(req.ip)) {
    // console.log('LAN --> no auth needed');
    next();
  } else {
    console.log(req.ip + ' --> WAN --> auth to pass');

    function unauthorized(res) {
      console.log('unauthorized --> 401');
      res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Authorization Required');
      return res.sendStatus(401);
    }

    var user = basicAuth(req);
    console.log('basicAuth user:', user);

    if (!user || !user.name || !user.pass) {
      console.log('!user');
      return unauthorized(res);
    }

    user_tools.checkCredentials(user.name, user.pass, function(valid) {
      console.log('valid:', valid);
      if (valid) {
        return next();
      } else {
        return unauthorized(res);
      }
    });
  }
};

app.get('/restricted_api/:value', auth, function(req, res) {
  // do authorised stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with `bcrypt.compare` taking 1 minute which lead me to assume request has exited.

Using a smaller `rounds` value (for seed, when hashing the password) gave me much quicker response time of the `compare` operation.

FYI, when comparing password with hash created with seed by using default value for `rounds` (10 --> 2^10 rounds) it was taking 1 minute on my Raspberry Pi. On the other hand, password hashed with seed with 5 (2^5) `rounds` gave me `compare()` response of 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

In connect basicAuth middleware (http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/basicAuth.html), req.user is set. In your express 4 version, I cannot find that part. I am not sure if that caused the fail because function(req, res) needs req.user.

Comment: Nah, I believe that isn't the case. I've added `req.user = user;` but the real problem is that `console.log('valid:', valid)` is never showing as the `auth()` middleware exits before my async finction `checkCredentials()` returns. The Express 3.x had the middleware you linked which had `var pause = utils.pause(req);` for async requests which I don't have.

Comment: That was one thing that I have noticed. I have used pause in one auth function in order to capture the data/events of request during the authentication and then release those data/events. See this for details (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412157/how-to-avoid-the-data-of-request-stream-loss-after-doing-some-authentication-on). If you needs to send request body/file, then you will need the pause. It seems you have found the real problem.